# After upgrading Angular, webpack module source-map-loader is throwing "this.getOptions is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, source-maps

I am currently building my angular project via [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulerules) with [source-map-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-loader) to extract source maps, like so:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

This works fine with my Angular 11 build.
Once I upgrade my angular packages to Angular 12, I begin to get the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/index.js:21:24)
```

Removing this section from my webpack module allows the build to succeed but I am no longer extracting the source maps, causing my bundle to increase in size.

I have tried upgrading source-map-loader to latest version and did not change the error.
I have dug into the node_module and it is complaining about this section of code:

```
async function loader(input, inputMap) {
  const options = this.getOptions(_options.default);
```

I have seen may other questions on here in regards to sass-loader and other style loaders for Vue but this is for Angular and is mad about extracting source maps.

There are some [breaking changes](https://angular.io/guide/updating-to-version-12#breaking-changes-in-angular-version-12) when going to Angular 12 but upgrading to webpack 5.0.0 did not seem to make a difference

What are some other things I can do to debug this?

Comment: What's your `package.json` ? Did you upgrade `Webpack` to 5?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the source code v[1.1.3](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader/blob/v1.1.3/src/index.js) we do see

```
import { getOptions } from "loader-utils";
```

But after [v2.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader/blob/v2.0.0/src/index.js) or even [v3.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader/blob/v3.0.0/src/index.js), this import was deleted.

It came from the library [loader-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loader-utils)

Since v2.0, [`package.json`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader/blob/master/package.json) doesn't import it anymore.

Looks like it has been deprecated, `getOptions` should be use from `Webpack` type instead of `loader-utils`.

Maybe your error come from a conflict with an old dependencie from your `node_modules`, you should remove the old one from your directory and try again

```
rm -rf node_modules/@types/loader-utils
rm -rf node_modules/loader-utils
```

Comment: thanks for your response, was able to get by updating Webpack 5 in the consuming library and upgrading the Angular plugin as it needed a new version that passed the the compiled pieces to the loaders.

Comment: Nice, good to know :)